# How is best_score_ actually calculated in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm doing a project and I needed to estimate the density function of a distribution. So I used GridSearchCV:

```
param_grid = {'kernel': ['gaussian', 'epanechnikov', 'exponential', 'linear', 'tophat', 'cosine'], 'bandwidth': np.linspace (0.01, .5, 1000)}

grid = GridSearchCV (
     estimator = KernelDensity (),
     param_grid = param_grid,
     n_jobs = -1,
     cv = 2,
     verbose = 0,
   )
```

I printed print(grid.best_params_, ":", grid.best_score_)

But best_score gives me values between 16 with cv = 2 or 800 with cv = 50. I really don't understand what best_score_ means because in the library it says that:

best_score_float

```
 Mean cross-validated score of the best_estimator
```

How is it really calculated? Do we look for large or small values of best_estimator to have a better fit?

Thank you

Comment: take a look at: https://pretagteam.com/question/how-is-scikitlearn-gridsearchcv-bestscore-calculated

Comment: The hyperparameter searches always try to maximize the score (easy enough to check from the `cv_results_`); hence things like **negative** mean squared error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not pass a scorer to GridSearchCV, it defaults to the scoring in the estimator. In your case, it is the total loglikelihood, see [help page for kernelDensity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.score). You can check it using an example below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

param_grid = {'kernel': ['gaussian'], 
'bandwidth': [1.0]}

kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
X = np.random.uniform(0,1,1000).reshape(-1,1)

grid = GridSearchCV (
     estimator = KernelDensity (),
     param_grid = param_grid,
     n_jobs = -1,
     cv = kf,
     verbose = 0,
   )

grid.fit(X)

grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
array([-497.83585627])

scores = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    ker = KernelDensity().fit(X[train_index])
    scores.append(ker.score(X[test_index]))

np.mean(scores)
-497.8358562692174
```